# Sharing Page B post on Page A wall using an application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Assumption :
I’m Admin of Page A.
I’m NOT Admin of Page B.

As Page A, I can take any post that is displayed on Page B and SHARE it onto Page A this is achieved by clicking on the word “Share” that appears under the image in a post.

Now, I want to achieve this automatically with code. Say I see a post on Page B wall, I find its post id and feed it to my application. Now my application will try to share this post from Page B to my Page A. I want to replicate manual process of sharing from Page B wall to my Page through application.

Currently, I have not started working on this code. I just want to know is if this is at all possible and what approaches can I take probably achieve this.

Note :  I don't want to post on my page wall as my own post.The Post should appear as shared from Page B wall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible as I have done some testing recently. Even if you are admin of *both* PageA and PageB, you cannot post on PageA as PageB (where the "voice" is set to PageB and the post is displayed as authored by PageB). The voice (ie. "authored by PageB") works on pages you admin and posts on the page with the voice belonging to the *same page*. At least that's how the API is behaving currently.

Extending this to share: Not sure how you were thinking of executing the share, but sharing on a page via the API is basically posting with the same context as another post.

Comment: yeah that's what I want to know if sharing from other wall can be achieved programmatically. One way I can think of sharing Post B's wallpost to Page A is probably by getting contents of post and then posting it on Page  A wall as Page A. but that would be like stealing the content, not exactly sharing. My clients wants that if he sees a good post on some random Page B wall he wants a way in which he can schedule sharing of this post in his page wall. It's probably not possible.